# How can I hide or remove deprecation notices from gem 1.8.x?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, deprecated

The gem command (version 1.8.1 and probably 1.8.0) spews out a tonne of deprecation notices on every invocation. It is painful to page through a screen of warnings to look at test output.

Is there an easy way to hide deprecation notices ?  Especially the warning :

```
NOTE: Gem::Specification#default_executable= is deprecated with no replacement.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using RVM, the following command will fix it:

rvm rubygems current